# Hexadecimals adding and subtracting

Tags: c++, hex

I have this code so far. When I add the two negative integers, the answer is positive    instead of negative. How do I fix this?
I think the 0x80000000 is the smallest possible value for a integer

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
unsigned int maxInt = 0x7FFFFFFF;
int num1 = 7;
signed int minInt = 0x80000000;
int num2 = -21;
float num3 = 1;
float i;

cout<<"The value of the first variable is: "<<maxInt<<endl;
cout<<"The value of the second variable is: "<< num1<<endl;
cout<<"Addition of the two numbers: "<< maxInt + num1 <<endl;
cout<<endl;

cout<<"The value of the first variable is: "<<minInt<<endl;
cout<<"The value of the second variable is "<<num2<<endl;
cout<<"Addition of the two numbers: "<< minInt + num2 <<endl;
cout<<endl;

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What was the output?  What did you expect it to be?

Comment: You don't fix it, adding a negative number to `minInt` would yield an out-of-range result, the addition overflows, that's undefined behaviour.

Comment: Any subtraction from `minInt` will cause an underflow, which will be represented as a positive number.  You can't fix this with `int`s as there aren't enough bits.  You'll need a data type (e.g. `longlong`) that has more bits.

Comment: You're rolling over.  This is the sticking point people have with fixed width integer representation.  How do you fix it?  Either use smaller numbers or increase the number of bits you're using to represent these numbers (e.g. long).

Comment: When you take the largest possible integer and add a positive integer to that value it is suppose to wrap around to the largest minimum integer and count down from there? The result I get is 2147483654 since 2147483647 is largest possible integer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adding 0x80000000 and -21 gives a result of 0x7FFFFFDF. This number in decimal is 2147483615. This happens because the leftmost bit is used to determine the sign. You're getting an underflow, which in this case wraps around to the maximum integer and counts down from there. The same thing should be happening the other way with adding the two positive integers, except that it would wrap around to 0 as it's unsigned, but it is undefined behaviour when you overflow or underflow.

As the comments say, you could use a bigger type:

```
int64_t result = static_cast<int64_t>(maxInt) + num1;
int64_t result2 = static_cast<int64_t>(minInt) - num2;
```

Comment: A good explanation.  Can you answer the second part of the question:  "How do I fix this?"

Comment: @AdamLiss, duly noted. I added some code for it with a type guaranteed to be 64 bits to hold the result.

Comment: -1. The example is wrong. Overflow will occur before assignment to a longer type. Oops.

Comment: When you take the largest possible integer and add a positive integer to that value it is suppose to wrap around to the largest minimum integer and count down from there? The result I get is 2147483654 since 2147483647 is largest possible integer

Comment: @user1251302, overflow and underflow are undefined behaviour, but most times you'll see them wrap around due to the way the bits are represented. `0x7FFFFFFF + 1 = 0x80000000` Now guess what `0x80000000` is. It's the minimum.

Comment: alright that makes sense. Why is my positive number not wrapping around and my negative number this. I'm trying to understand what happens during underflow and overflow in C++.

Comment: @user1251302, ah. That behaviour is actually very well-defined. Your number is the maximum *signed* int, but what you've got is an *unsiged* int. Therefore, you've only got half of the maximum (minus 1). When you add 7, it's not an overflow. However, if the initial value was `0xFFFFFFFF`, then it would be an overflow, causing undefined behaviour that is most likely to wrap around to 0, since the range of an *unsigned* int is 0 to 2^32 - 1.

Comment: Oh ok. I been trying to write a for loop that takes 1 and multiplies it by .1 each time to show when underflow occurs, but I'm not sure how to keep multiplying the result by .1. It only goes back to the original value and I get a bunch of .1's.

Comment: I just want to say that since posting this, I've learned that unsigned ints overflowing are **not** UB like signed ones. In my last comment, if the value was `0xFFFFFFFF`, and you add one, it is perfectly defined going to 0.